# Appending variables inside dynamic sql in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having trouble building a dynamic sql string to run an openquery. When I print the query string it evaluates the variable name as string instead of the actual value. Here's what I have:

```
Declare @tsql varchar(1000)

Declare @book_review_start as date

Declare @book_review_end as date

set @book_review_start =  convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-2, 0), 120)

set @book_review_end =  convert(varchar(10), DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), -2), 120)

Set @tsql = 'select * from openquery(authorsdb, ''select distinct ssn as bsn
from authors.dbo.nytimes where review_date between '' + @book_review_start + 'and' + '@book_review_end' + 'and review = 'annual'
        and city_name = ''
        and review_hrs = 0
        and review_days = 0')'
```

That throws all kinds of conversion errors and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need 1 or more extra `'` single quote characters in 1 or more places in your statement.

2) The `DATE` values need to converted to string / `VARCHAR` since you are concatenating string to generate the dynamic SQL statement.

The following works.

```
DECLARE @tsql VARCHAR(1000)    
DECLARE @book_review_start AS DATE    
DECLARE @book_review_end AS DATE

SET @book_review_start = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-2, 0)    
set @book_review_end = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), -2)

Set @tsql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(authorsdb, ''SELECT DISTINCT ssn AS bsn FROM authors.dbo.nytimes WHERE review_date BETWEEN''' 
+  CONVERT(varchar(20),@book_review_start) + ''' AND ''' + CONVERT(varchar(20),@book_review_end ) + ''''
+ ' AND review = ''annual'' AND city_name = '''' AND review_hrs = 0 AND review_days = 0 )'

PRINT @tsql
```

The OUTPUT of the `PRINT` Statement is as follows.

> SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(authorsdb, 'SELECT DISTINCT ssn AS bsn FROM
>   authors.dbo.nytimes WHERE review_date BETWEEN'2016-05-01' AND
>   '2016-06-30' AND review = 'annual' AND city_name = '' AND review_hrs =
>   0 AND review_days = 0 )

Comment: That does seem to work but I'm confused as to the missing parenthesis to match the opening paren before authorsdb.

Comment: also, why are the dates being converted twice - once in 'set' and again down below?

Comment: Hi @DamonMatt, 1) My original answer was missing the closing `)`, I updated it now and tested it. My bad.  2) Like you pointed out, the conversion back and forth is not needed. I didn't notice that in your initial question as I was focused on fixing your `'` quotes issue. Again my bad. Have updated the answer with both these fixes and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your query issues are
    - `@book_review_start` / end declared `DATE`, should be `VARCHAR` to take part in concatenation
    - to have a quote in a quoted string you need double quote, to have quoted string in a quoted string you need `4 quotes`
Try

```
Declare @tsql varchar(1000)

Declare @book_review_start varchar(10)

Declare @book_review_end varchar(10)

set @book_review_start =  convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE())-2, 0), 120)

set @book_review_end =  convert(varchar(10), DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), -2), 120)

Set @tsql = 'select * from openquery(authorsdb, ''select distinct ssn as bsn
from authors.dbo.nytimes where review_date between ''''' + @book_review_start + ''''' and ''''' + @book_review_end + ''''' and review = ''''annual''''
        and city_name = ''''''''
        and review_hrs = 0
        and review_days = 0'')' ;

select @tsql;
```

Comment: Gives an error: The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator

Comment: Are you sure, there's no `date` variables in my code.

Comment: OK, but does it gives the result needed? See it runnig http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/517238/appending-variables-inside-dynamic-sql-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

If the intent is to eventually do this:

```
exec sp_executesql @tsql
```

then, as a minimum you must:

1  Make @tsql an nvarchar variable as opposed to varchar.

2 As suggested by Serg, all single quotes in the sql part become 4 single quotes.  For example, this:

```
and city_name = ''
```

becomes this:

```
and city_name = ''''''''
```

3  You need spaces around words.  For example this:

```
where review_date between '' + @book_review_start + 'and'
```

must be this:

```
where review_date between ' + @book_review_start + ' and '
```

This should get you started.  Read the other answers as well.